# Border-radius and background not connecting in Firefox only

Tags: firefox, css

Here's my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/edelman/NJHLU/

Basically, if there's a border radius on an element with a border, the border and background don't actually touch, creating a little inner white circle that looks stupid crappy.

Things I've tried that haven't worked:

- `background-clip` and all of the possible values
- `overflow: hidden`
- `border-collapse` with both values

Nothing seems to work. Is this just a FF rendering bug that I have to just deal with?

I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6001281/css3-border-color-border-radius-and-background-color-resulting-in-strange-beh), but I don't have the luxury of wrapping, as I'm doing this CSS on generated content (`:before` pseudo element)

**EDIT:** I have also tried using `box-shadow` in lieu of a border, but that has the same problems.

Comment: Great experiment. It's simply weird. :)

Comment: Firefox has had issues drawing rounded corners with `border-radius` for years. It was even worse in Firefox 2 when the rounded corners **weren't even anti-aliased**.

Comment: It does look like a Gecko rendering bug, and it'd be really nice to report things like this instead of (or in addition to) just working around them!  It's not like browsers are immutable black boxes, and if you file the bug in Firefox or Chrome it can be fixed in what users are using within a few months.  In any case, I filed https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=704399

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the technique described in the answer you linked to.  Add a FF hack:

```
-moz-box-shadow:0px 0px 0px #2eb8ae;
```

Comment: It worked for me in the fiddle you created with FF 8.0 http://jsfiddle.net/brian3f/szKKC/

Comment: @Jason: What version of Firefox are you on?

Comment: @BrianFisher - wow.. using a no-pixel `box-shadow` WITH `border` solves the problem! thank you!