# Rounded corners in Firefox: space between border and background

Tags: html, firefox, css

I have a div that I am applying rounded corners to.

Here is my [demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5yAkZ/).

```
<div>&nbsp;</div>
```

```
div {
    margin: 20px;
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 15px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    background-color: #4c66a1;
    border: 2px solid #4c66a1;
}
```

I also have a border and background color applied to this div. The issue arises in Firefox. There is a small amount of whitespace between the border and the background-color of the div (see images below). It is very minimal, but people have noticed it nonetheless. It looks like a lighting effect on the corner.

Is this a known issue with rounded corners in Firefox? IE, Chrome, and Opera are fine.

FYI/ For the purposes of illustrating the issue I have made the border and background-color the same even though it's redundant. It makes the whitespace stand out more.

```
 Firefox      Chrome/IE/Opera
```

[image]        
[image]

Comment: it didn't reproduce when i changed the color to red

Comment: @FosterZ: Red still does it for me. Just less noticeable. Crank the radius up to 50 and you will see it, just about. Edit: actually, I can still see it at 15, eagle eyes me ;)

Comment: yep, that's why I used similar colors in the sample to illustrate the issue better. bright colors will take your eye away from it and the issue is much less noticeable. if you really want to see it happen try to create a circle using border-radius. the whitespace will encircle the whole div.

Comment: Fixed it! Just use colour `#FFF` ... yeah but really, got to be a Firefox render thing (either a bug or by bad design)

Comment: @musefan I can't use white because I would like a border and a background color.

Comment: do you want border with color around the round ractangle ??

Comment: @FosterZ yes. softer complimentary colors on the border and background seem to illustrate the issue better. contrasting colors take away from the effect.

Comment: It's really noticeable if the border width is 4px.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS3 - border-color, border-radius and background color resulting in strange behaviour](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6001281/css3-border-color-border-radius-and-background-color-resulting-in-strange-beh)

Comment: What's exact version of your Firefox?

Comment: I confirm this issue. It seems to be a bug in Firefox; you should report it if it is not reported yet.

Comment: Cannot reproduce under Firefox 11 while can reproduce under Firefox 3.6. So the bug is probably fixed in some of versions of Firefox between 3.6 and 11.

Comment: FYI/ I'm using FF 10.0.2, so I guess it must be fixed in 11.

Comment: @j08691 thanks for the link! I tried searching for similar and nothing came up. a good answer in that thread as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interestingly, if we change it to dotted, the white goes away:

```
div {
    margin: 20px;
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    -moz-border-radius: 30px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 30px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 30px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    background-color: #4c66a1;
    border: 2px dotted #4c66a1;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5yAkZ/23/

**EDIT** had invalid css previously

Comment: that's invalid css. you have to specify a style or the border won't even display.

Comment: You're correct, what I had was invalid. However, if we change it to dotted, the issue appears to go away (at least on my end) - acts like a bug with rounded solid borders.

Comment: wow, really good catch! from this I did some experimenting and found that if you use the `double` style... the issue is fixed! since my border is only `2px` you actually can't detect the double border, it's only noticeable at > `3px` where it splits into 2 distinct borders. Thank you very much for your help! This should be filed in a bug report somewhere...

Answer (score 1):

See https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=704399 which is fixed in Firefox 11 and newer.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out is this you want
    [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fosterz/RELkx/4/)

```
<div id='ex1' class='exampleRound'>&nbsp;</div>
```

```
#ex1{
    border-radius: 50px;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
}
.exampleRound {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #4c66a1;
    border: 5px solid pink;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    padding: 20px 40px;
    margin:20px
}
```

Comment: switch those bright colors out for softer tones and the issue still persists.