# CSS: Making two custom/criss cross lines embodying text?

Tags: css

[image: http://i57.tinypic.com/30c66hy.png]

I was wondering if there's a way to make these two criss cross lines on the edges. The black box will be filled with texts. Is there anyway to do this in CSS? Thank you!

Comment: To all the downvoters and close-voters:  George Stocker♦ and Shog9♦ have stated that questions like these are apparently on topic and allowed; see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28673567/how-do-i-draw-an-incomplete-circle-with-css) and the related [Meta discussion](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286757/is-it-always-a-good-idea-to-demand-the-op-post-some-code/286760#286760)

Comment: sorry i'm really new to css so i'm not even sure how to approach this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a gradient background on pseudo elements to make the cross lines.

```
.border {
    width:80%;
    margin:2em auto;
    padding:2em;
    position:relative;

}
.border::before {
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    left: -10px;
    top:-10px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent 24px, #ddd 24px, #ddd 26px, transparent 26px), linear-gradient(to right, transparent 24px, #ddd 24px, #ddd 26px, transparent 26px);
}
.border::after {
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    right:-10px;
    bottom:-10px;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent 74px, #ddd 74px, #ddd 76px, transparent 76px), linear-gradient(to right, transparent 74px, #ddd 74px, #ddd 76px, transparent 76px);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/e9dwbdyn/1/