# How to create these shapes using CSS3

Tags: css, css-shapes

I am creating a responsive website. I want to create below shape in CSS3. using ul li.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried anything? Do you have any code to show? Are you expecting someone here to just write the code for you?

Comment: @BigRabbit - apparently, based on comments by George Stocker [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28673567/how-do-i-draw-an-incomplete-circle-with-css-and-in-it-how-to-put-a-picture), questions like these are on-topic as-is now...

Comment: yes I did using js fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/tmjLet8u/

Comment: but not getting exact curve as in image

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables I don't agree with this at all. Since when did this become a free labour job board?

Comment: Ok thanks for sharing George Stocker

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables, I tried a lot to achieve this. I just needed some help to achieve this, nothing more than that. 
This is not a paid assignment.

Comment: @user3148906: As indicated in the comment by George, showing code is not mandatory but doing so always helps. It atleast demonstrates to potential answerers that you understand the basics and would be able to decipher the answer. Coming to the question itself, it might be a better idea to use a pseudo-element spanning the entire width, make it into an ellipse using `border-radius` and then position it below the list elements.

Comment: Harry, thanks a lot for your help. It actually increased my knowledge of using pseudo-element.

Answer (score 4):

you could use a pseudo element, and have overflow:hidden set on the parent container.

```css
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #222;
}
.wrap {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background: #222;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.wrap div {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 22%;
  margin-left: 2%;
  background: lightblue;
  transition: all 0.6s;
  line-height:200px;
  text-align:center;
}
.wrap:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -25%;
  left: 0;
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #222;
  z-index: 8;
}
div.withImage {
  background: url(http://placekitten.com/g/300/300);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
.wrap div:hover:before {
  opacity: 1;
}
.wrap div:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: blue;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.6s;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div>ONE</div>
  <div>TWO</div>
  <div>THREE</div>
  <div class="withImage">FOUR</div>
</div>
```

## NOTE

**This has been done using `Divs`. I have left it as an exercise for the OP to alter this code for `ul li`.**

This can also be altered to include Dynamically added elements: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/jbutler483/dubyfvhm/)