# Rounded CSS border looks pixelated

Tags: image, css, border, rounded-corners

I need some help to fix my rounded border. It looks so ugly. I want it more smooth, but I can't seem to fix it no matter what. I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Here is a picture of it:

[image]

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="sidebar">
    <!-- User avatar/message/notification/settings buttons -->
    <div class="userpanel">
        <div class="userpanel-image">
            <img src="image.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="userpanel-buttons">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-bell"></span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is my CSS:

```
.sidebar > .userpanel > .userpanel-image img {
    border: 1px solid white;
    border-radius: 25px;
    margin: 3px;
    margin-right: 25px;
}
```

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19959229/4700944) post just might be what you are looking for to solve your problem.

Comment: @Alex It looks better but still kind of pixelated in my small size (50x50px images).

Comment: Well, not sure what you would expect necessarily.  It's a high contrast border (white on very very dark blue) and only 1 pixel wide.  Browsers have limitations and anti aliasing (although present) is not always going to be the ideal blur level for every scenario.  I suggest lowering the contrast to make it look less pixelated.

Comment: try css `background-clip: padding-box;`

Answer (score 12):

This ultimately depends upon the [pixel density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pixel_density) of the monitor you are using.

> Pixels per inch (PPI) or pixels per centimeter (PPCM) is a measurement of the pixel density (resolution) of an electronic image device, such as a computer monitor or television display, or image digitizing device such as a camera or image scanner. Horizontal and vertical density are usually the same, as most devices have square pixels, but differ on devices that have non-square pixels.
>
> For example, a 15 inch (38 cm) display whose dimensions work out to 12 inches (30.48 cm) wide by 9 inches (22.86 cm) high, capable of a maximum 1024×768 (or XGA) pixel resolution, can display around 85 PPI in both the horizontal and vertical directions. This figure is determined by dividing the width (or height) of the display area in pixels by the width (or height) of the display area in inches. It is possible for a display to have different horizontal and vertical PPI measurements (e.g., a typical 4:3 ratio CRT monitor showing a 1280×1024 mode computer display at maximum size, which is a 5:4 ratio, not quite the same as 4:3). The apparent PPI of a monitor depends upon the screen resolution (that is, the number of pixels) and the size of the screen in use; a monitor in 800×600 mode has a lower PPI than does the same monitor in a 1024×768 or 1280×960 mode.

Monitors with a higher pixel density will tend to smooth curves much better visually.

There's really nothing you can generally do to improve the pixel density display via HTML/CSS or really, anything. You merely have to learn to live with the quality of your monitor or upgrade it.

In some cases, applying a slight 1px `box-shadow` the same color as your circle can assist in the monitor anti-aliasing. However, that's not 100% successful either.

Answer (score 8):

You're definetly not doing anything wrong.

Maybe that just because the border is too thin. Try to change `border: 1px solid white;` to 2px, 3px, or whatever you like. Give it try.

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately i had the same problem several times. I think this might be a render problem which cant be solved 100%. Maybe you can use the workaround i used for my "border-problem" to make it look sharper (I did not test it on every single browser so u might have to check that out)

```css
body {background:black;}

div {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  display:block;
  background:#fff;
  border-radius:100%;
  padding:2px;
}

img {
  display:block;
  border-radius:100%;
  display:block;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/100" alt=""> 
</div>
```

Comment: This definitely resulted in the most noticeable improvement, especially for smaller images.

Answer (score 7):

For me this looks best:

```css
.userpanel-image {  
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px 1px white;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.userpanel-image img {
  width: 98px;
  height: 98px;
}
```

Comment: 0 votes, but this worked like a charm. 1px border was pixelated, switching to a box-shadow is smooth as butter.

Answer (score 4):

Usually when I'm faced with this problem, I just reduce the contrast of the colors to help ease the pixelated anti-aliasing (as I mentioned in my comment).  This is not always an option however.  The real problem you are facing is that the browser will apply a certain amount of anti-aliasing to prevent complete jaggedness and you don't really have control over the intensity of that anti-aliasing that's applied.  Here's an alternative that you can use to help take control of the appearance.  You can use box-shadow to supplement or replace your existing border:

```css
body {
  background: #223;
  padding-bottom: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

div {
  margin-top: 25px;
}

img {
  display:inline-block;
  
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid white;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

div + div img {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px 0 white;
}

div + div + div img {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px white;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<div>border only: <img src="//placehold.it/50/933/FFF"></div>
<div>border + box-shadow: <img src="//placehold.it/50/933/FFF">
<div>box-shadow only: <img src="//placehold.it/50/933/FFF">
```

Comment: My Chrome (Ubuntu 17.10) renders all of them pixelated, holy cow!

Comment: +1 for "reducing the contrast of the colors" -- I just changed my border from `black` to `darkgray` and was fine.